# JavaScript Regex to find string that ends in ".js" but not "-min.js"

Tags: javascript, regex

As the title states: Can any one help me figure out how to write a JavaScript regex expression that matches a string that end in ".js" but fails when given a string that ends in "-min.js".

Examples:

hello.js -> match

hellomin.js -> match

hello-min.js -> no match

hello-min-hello.js -> match

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookahead:

`(?!-min)[\w-]{4}\.js$`

**Update**

This will also work for less than 4 characters before the `.js`:

`(?:(?!-min)[\w-]{4}|^[\w-]{1,3})\.js$`

Comment: This looks like it works but will fail if there are less than four characters preceding ".js"

Comment: @Sidawy - Updated answer to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the pseudo-inverted matching based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word):

```
^((?!-min\.).)*\.js$
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JS does not support negative lookbehind, lets use negative lookahead!

```
var str = 'asset/34534534/jquery.test-min.js',
    reversed = str.split('').reverse().join('');

// And now test it
/^sj\.(?!nim-)/.test(reversed); // will give you false if str has min.js at the end
```

Funny, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have extended @robinCTS's regex to match file paths with more than one dot (for example with version number at the end of filename) and also a string that ends in ".min.js":

```
(?:(?!(-|\.)min)[\w\.-]{4}|^[\w\.-]{1,3})\.js$
```

Examples:

- hello.js -> match
- hellomin.js -> match
- hellomin-2.4.3.js -> match
- hello-min-hello.js -> match
- hello-min.js -> no match
- hello.min.js -> no match
- hellomin-2.4.3-min.js -> no match
- hellomin-2.4.3.min.js -> no match

Answer (score -1):

You can use negative lookbehind :

```
(?<!-min)\.js$
```

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/O1PEEBbAjF)

Comment: JS regex doesn't support negative lookbehind! ;)